# OpenUI5: Grid: Does it support Groupings?

Tags: grid, grouping, sapui5

I am looking at various widget libraries, and ran across OpenUI5.  It appears to be reasonably complete.  The one thing I can't seem to find is any grouping functionalities for Grids.  For example, in other grids, I can grab a column, and drag/drop it into the header portion of the grid, and now my data is grouped by that column.  I can do this for multiple levels.  After doing this, the data is laid out almost like a combination tree/grid control.  I find this very valuable.  Does OpenUI5 support this? If not, is it in the plans?  Here is an example

[image: Example of Grouping by City]

Answer (score 0):

OpenUI5 has two main Table controls, [one for it's Mobile-oriented library (sap.m)](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/sample/sap.ui.table.sample.Basic/preview), and [one for it's Desktop-oriented library (sap.ui.table)](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/test-resources/sap/ui/table/demokit/Table.html).

These table's do support drag-and-drop of columns, but for re-ordering not for grouping.

The [merging feature of the sap.m table](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/sample/sap.m.sample.TableMergeCells/preview) may be of interest, though it's not really the same as grouping. Also note [the multi-header feature](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/sample/sap.ui.table.sample.MultiHeader/preview).

Another control similar to your use-case could be the [TreeTable](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/test-resources/sap/ui/table/demokit/TreeTable.html).

But, in short, **it does not look like out-of-the-box OpenUI5 has a control that exactly matches your use-case**.

I will say that it is pretty easy to extend OpenUI5 controls as they have a nice OO-flavored jQuery extension approach.

You could also open an issue on [their GitHub page](https://github.com/SAP/openui5) to make this a priority for a future release.